# MySQL: Does more "where" conditions increase speed?

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
ID | Name  | Status
```

With millions of entries. If I do a select:

```
SELECT * from table where ID = 949442
```

Will this query be in any way faster than this one:

```
SELECT * from table where ID = 949442 AND status = "OPEN"
```

Assuming that this row could have an OPEN or CLOSED status?

Comment: Have you tried running them?

Comment: Depends on your data structure and if a suitable index exists.

Comment: You may having index(access structure) for ID field so fast, But due to no index in status field it filter later on selected by ID field hence slower

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding more `WHERE` conditions will not make your queries faster in general. For example, sometimes adding an `OR` condition make things slow. Usually adding more conditions using `AND` will make the query faster even if just because the result set is smaller and thus less data has to be transmitted over the wire.

What makes query faster is when you write a `WHERE` condition that matches an index:
[8.3. Optimization and Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Answer (score 1):

If `ID` is a unique column (as it appears to be) then it's unlikely that extra constraints are going to affect performance in any measurable way, positive or negative.  The DB engine can already locate that specific row in O(log n) time, and checking the value of a column in a row you already have located is an O(1) operation.